# override the query in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel:

I want to fetch the result from database where `id`='6' and `is_delete_list = 0`. I am using the following query :

```
'end_date' =>Quotation::where('id',$conttt->quotation_id)->where('is_delete_list','=','1')->first(),
```

It is returning null data while the data exists in database. When I make Research on this using debugging then I saw that it is using the query :

```
select * from `quotations` where `id` = '8' and `quotations`.`deleted_at` is null and (`quotations`.`is_delete_list` = '0' and `quotations`.`is_converted_list` = '0' and `quotations`.`is_quotation_invoice_list` = '0') limit 1
```

Please help me guys How I can update this query and use my custom query as per the above example

Comment: I'm not entirely certain that the query you're seeing in the second code snippet is associated with the Eloquent query you have in the first. If you create a dummy route and just `dd(Quotation::where('id', 6)->where('is_delete_list','=','1')->first());`, what do you get?

Comment: It is returning blank while I have data in db

Comment: Your question and code contradict themselves... *"... and is_delete_list = 0"* but your query says `->where('is_delete_list','=','1')`. Which one is it?